# Array based indexing of an ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am not understanding `numpy.take` though it seems like it is the function I want. I have an ndarray and I want to use another ndarray to index into the first.

```
import numpy as np

# Create a matrix
A = np.arange(75).reshape((5,5,3))

# Create the index array
idx = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Given the above, I want to index `A` by the values in `idx`. I thought `take`does this, but it doesn't output what I expected.

```
# Index the 3rd dimension of the A matrix by the idx array.

Asub = np.take(A, idx)

print(f'Value in A at 1,1,1 is {A[1,1,1]}')
print(f'Desired index from idx {idx[1,1]}')

print(f'Value in Asub at [1,1,1] {Asub[1,1]} <- thought this would be 19')
```

I was expecting to see the value at the idx location one the value in `A` based on `idx`:

```
Value in A at 1,1,1 is 19
Desired index from idx 1
Value in Asub at [1,1,1] 1 <- thought this would be 19
```

Comment: Did you see the bit about flattening the array when `axis` is None, the default?  It will be hard to check the results if the values are random

Comment: I changed it to be non random. What I want to do is to use the idx array and select the values in the third dimension of the A matrix.  The example output `Asub` I thought would be the value 19 as it was at `A[1,1, idx[1,1]]`.  So, I want to create a new matrix that is essentially `A[:,:,idx]` but don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to create row and col indices that `broadcast` with the third dimension one, i.e a (5,1) and (5,) that pair with the (5,5) idx:

```
In [132]: A[np.arange(5)[:,None],np.arange(5), idx]
Out[132]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  6, 10, 13],
       [16, 19, 21, 25, 28],
       [31, 33, 37, 39, 43],
       [46, 49, 51, 54, 57],
       [61, 64, 67, 70, 72]])
```

This ends up picking values from `A[:,:,0]` and `A[:,:,1]`.  This takes the values of `idx` as integers, in the range of valid (0,1,2) (for shape 3).  They aren't boolean selectors.

`Out[132][1,1]` is 19, same as `A[1,1,1]`; `Out[132][1,2]` is the same as `A[1,2,0]`.

`take_along_axis` gets the same values, but with an added dimension:

```
In [142]: np.take_along_axis(A, idx[:,:,None], 2).shape
Out[142]: (5, 5, 1)

In [143]: np.take_along_axis(A, idx[:,:,None], 2)[:,:,0]
Out[143]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  6, 10, 13],
       [16, 19, 21, 25, 28],
       [31, 33, 37, 39, 43],
       [46, 49, 51, 54, 57],
       [61, 64, 67, 70, 72]])
```

The iterative equivalent might be easier to understand:

```
In [145]: np.array([[A[i,j,idx[i,j]] for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)])
Out[145]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  6, 10, 13],
       [16, 19, 21, 25, 28],
       [31, 33, 37, 39, 43],
       [46, 49, 51, 54, 57],
       [61, 64, 67, 70, 72]])
```

If you have trouble expressing an action in "vectorized" array ways, go ahead an write an integrative version.  It will avoid a lot of ambiguity and misunderstanding.

Another way to get the same values, treating the `idx` values as True/False booleans is:

```
In [146]: np.where(idx, A[:,:,1], A[:,:,0])
Out[146]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  6, 10, 13],
       [16, 19, 21, 25, 28],
       [31, 33, 37, 39, 43],
       [46, 49, 51, 54, 57],
       [61, 64, 67, 70, 72]])
```

Comment: Ah, `np.take_along_axis(A, idx[:,:,None], 2)` is what I was looking for. Though I don't understand why `idx` has to have a 3rd dimension.

Comment: @brechmos , `idx` shape must be compatible with `A` to be applicable for indexing and … . what the other indices e.g. `[0,1]` must be show?? it is `0` in your `idx`, so as I can realize from your question, it must not pick any value from `A` and can be set to `0`, and my answer was written on this manner, [which will be the fastest](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zzEm6gMc-3u6aDil2YsFLcD0_ZwqCyTt?usp=sharing). Did you evaluate my answer? here, my answer and `np.where` is faster than `np.take_along_axis` (`np.where` performance is improved in the new release), why `np.take_along_axis`?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can get the resulted array by broadcasting the idx array, to make its shape same as `A` to be multiplied, and then indexing to get the column `1` as:

```
Asub = (A * idx[:, :,  None])[:, :, 1]    # --> Asub[1, 1] = 19

# [[ 1  0  0 10 13]
#  [16 19  0 25 28]
#  [31  0 37  0 43]
#  [46 49  0  0  0]
#  [61 64 67 70  0]]
```

***I think it be the fastest way (or one of the bests), particularly for large arrays.***